# Terminal emulator with SSH command that works in Lollipop (PIE)

Tags: android, ssh

There are literally hundreds of terminal emulator apps for Android on Google play. I could spend a week testing them all.

Is there an Android shell app out there with an SSH and/or SFTP command that is position independent<sup>*</sup>, for Android Lollipop 5 and later?

What I need is a SFTP app that will run under Android 5+ that sets up an SSH connection **first**, then if the user successfully logs in then the SFTP session is initiated over the SSH connection. That way, if the target server has a welcome message upon successful login then it will still work, instead of `MESSAGE TOO LONG` error. So far, I have found nothing in the markets where the app behaves this way.

---

<sup>* Versions of Android 5 (Lollipop) and later have a requirement that the executable be compiled as a Position Independant Executable (PIE). PIE executables are loaded into memory at a random spot instead of a static spot in memory.</sup>